# how to split the words in R

Tags: r

I have a list of words in a file. For example they are NUT, CHANNEL, DIA, CARBON, STEEL , integrated, packaging, solutions

Now I have a sentence that says NUTCHANNELDIA 16U NCCARBONSTEEL. Now I need to split this output like below

```
a= NUTCHANNELDIA 16U NCCARBONSTEEL, integratedpackagingsolutions
a= split words(NUTCHANNELDIA 16U NCCARBONSTEEL, 
   integratedpackagingsolutions)
a= NUT CHANNEL DIA 16U NC CARBON STEEL
```

Is there any method for that

Comment: There must be a homework assignment. This is the third question on this topic I'm seeing in the main feed... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351585/splitting-the-sentence-that-has-2-similar-words and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52190969/looping-function-to-correct-sentences are the other two.

Comment: Please **do not** change your question after several people have already given you answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R option using `strsplit`.  We can try splitting on the following pattern:

```
(?<=NUT|CHANNEL|DIA|CARBON|STEEL)|(?<=.)(?=NUT|CHANNEL|DIA|CARBON|STEEL)
```

This will split if, at any point in the string, what either precedes or follows is one of your keywords.  Note that the `(?<=.)` term is necessary due to the way positive lookaheads in `strsplit` behave.

```
terms <- c("NUT", "CHANNEL", "DIA", "CARBON", "STEEL")
regex <- paste(terms, collapse="|")
a <- "NUTCHANNELDIA 16U NCCARBONSTEEL"
strsplit(a, paste0("(?<=", regex, ")|(?<=.)(?=", regex, ")"), perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "NUT"     "CHANNEL" "DIA"     " 16U NC" "CARBON"  "STEEL"
```

### Demo

The `16U NC` term has some leading whitespace which I didn't attempt to remove.  If this be a concern of yours, you could either trim whitespace on each term as you consume it, or we could try to modify the pattern to do that.

Comment: If my approach worked for one sentence, with a given set of keywords for splitting, then why wouldn't it work for another sentence?  Not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: This sounds like an error due to too many terms in the regex pattern.  You should edit your question and provide data which makes this problem reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple approach which might work for you:

```
word.list <- c("NUT", "CHANNEL", "DIA", "CARBON", "STEEL")

a <- "NUTCHANNELDIA 16U NCCARBONSTEEL"

for (word in word.list) {
  a <- gsub(word, paste0(word, " "), a)  
}

print(a)
[1] "NUT CHANNEL DIA  16U NCCARBON STEEL "
```

It is unclear to me, if you just want the string to be more readable, or to have it actually split up into a vector. In any case, the above should be fairly simple to modify.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it. But can we apply this a large data frame?

Comment: I tried this earlier and I got the result. What if there are more a's. See edited question

Comment: @Rentu Yes, it should work for a fairly large data frame. And if by "more a's" you mean `a` is a vector, then yes, it should work for that as well.