# Splitting the sentence that has 2 similar words

Tags: r

I need to split the words in a sentence but have some issues here

```
word.list1 <- c("rose","location","criminal","lotus","check","sing","single")
```

if you look at above code, sing and single are 2 words that I have in my list

Now i have a sentence

```
a <- "rosesinglelocationcriminalcheck"
```

Following code will split the words

```
for (word in word.list) {
  a <- gsub(word, paste0(word, " "), a)     }

> a1
```

`[1] "rose sing le location criminal check "`

Actually I need the output like below

```
> a1
```

`[1] "rose single location criminal check  "`

Since my I have both sing and single in my list. The code is taking sing actually. Is there anywhere to split the words

Comment: @R entu: Where is `single` and `sing` in your `word.list1`? I couldn't able to find `criminal` too. Could you please make sure these?

Comment: Apologies. I have edited my question. Please help

Comment: How do you decide to use `sing` or `single`?

Comment: I have these words in the my list. For now I can delete sing since the list it is small. What if I have many list and i can not look at each word and delete. In my sentence "rosesinglelocationcriminalcheck" , "single" has a meaning. But in "sing" and "le" , le does not have any meaning

Answer (score 1):

For that special case just switch whitespace in `gsub`:

```
word.list <- c("rose","location","criminal","lotus","check","sing","single")

a <- "rosesinglelocationcriminalcheck"
for (word in word.list) {
  a <- gsub(word, paste0(" ", word), a)     
}
a
#> [1] " rose  single location criminal check"
```

However I guess that approach is very limited. What about *singlet*? *sing*, *let* and *singlet* are all meaningful words.

Comment: yes I got your point . But in there is no let and singlet in my list of words

Comment: hi Birger, May i know what is switching white space ? And how it is applied here

Comment: Just change `paste0(word, " ")` to `paste0(" ", word)`